# SSD is not booting after waking up from sleep mode with low battery condition: Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, data-recovery

I've already found a way to erase the SSD and make it work again (https://askubuntu.com/questions/409684/image-or-reset-broken-ssd). But I need to find a way to **restore** my data. The data on my ssd is very important (bachelor thesis). Any ideas?

Here are some information I got using a livecd:

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8 MB, 8388608 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1 cylinders, total 16384 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

**hdparm -I /dev/sda**

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       INTEL SSDSA2BW120G3A                    
        Serial Number:      BAD_CTX     00000150
        Firmware Revision:  4PC10302
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:      16128
        LBA    user addressable sectors:      16384
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:      16384
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           8 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           8 MBytes 
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 1
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
           *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
           *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 500151795954bb60
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 001517
        Unique ID       : 95954bb60
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: Backup
1. Nobody wants backup, everybody wants restore.
2. To restore, you need a backup.
2. Have a backup.
...
http://adminzen.org/backup/

Comment: Ok understood I mean restore. Edited.

Comment: Try `testdisk`. And if your data is so very important, why are there no backups? I suggest using something like `git` (works great with LaTeX) and putting a “remote” on a USB thumb drive or the like. The more, the merrier.

Comment: I used git so I didn't lose everything but the work of nearly 6 hours I didn't push. I'll try testdisk. Other ideas are still welcome.

Comment: No luck with testdisk. It cant find any partition table

Comment: Um, just to be sure: Did you actually perform a secure erase before wanting to restore your data just now?

Comment: No of course not. As I found out theres no way to restore the data, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent hours trying to restore data from my ssd. Unfortunately there is **no way to restore**. But it is possible to get the SSD work again: https://askubuntu.com/a/409691/74290